# Eliminar caché automáticamente

Tags: javascript, html, css, cache

Tengo una web en html, css y javascript que continuamente se está actualizando. El problema es que los usuarios no ven el contenido actualizado ¿Cómo se puede hacer para que cada vez que los usuarios entren desde sus móviles u ordenadores vean el contenido actualizado a través del código y no vean la página como estaba hace 1 día o 2?

¿Esto serviría para que el usuario siempre vea el contenido actualizado?

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este código en html puedes hacer que la página no almacene caché:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

En php utilizaríamos:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 1 Jul 2000 05:00:00 GMT"); // Fecha en el pasado
?>
```

Y en .htaccess se puede usar lo siguiente:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|png|pdf|swf|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un opcion es obtener la IP desde la cual el usuario ingresa y luego hacer una funcion en la cual vos pases la ip de dicho usuario, al detectar la ip si existe en la memoria ara un clear cache de lo contrario no.

Answer (score 0):

Es mas un tema de configuración del servidor que de la página. Vos podrías definir los headers en el archivo HTML, pero si tu webserver tiene configuraciones por defecto o si estas usando un CDN, lo mismo. Creo que primero deberías revisar eso y evaluar que headers esta devolviendo el request a tu sitio para evaluar el response y en tal caso puede que sea cache del sitio, sino cache del browser.